# Kotlin. How to fill each line in a list with 5 unique numbers from 1 to 90?

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

I have a list of 3 lines:

```
private val line1 = mutableListOf<Int>()
private val line2 = mutableListOf<Int>()
private val line3 = mutableListOf<Int>()
val card = mutableListOf(line1, line2, line3)
```

I need to fill each line with 5 unique numbers from 1 to 90, how to do it?

I tried flow, but it doesn't work, because numbers in each line are the same.
And i need only 5 unique numbers in each line.

```
class Card {

    private val line1 = mutableListOf<Int>()
    private val line2 = mutableListOf<Int>()
    private val line3 = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val card = mutableListOf(line1, line2, line3)

    init {
        runBlocking {
            launch {
                Generator.flow.collect {
                    card.forEach { line ->
                        line.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do they need to be unique within each line, or over all three lines?

Comment: over all three lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

val result1 = MutableList(3) {
  generateSequence { Random.nextInt(1..90) }
    .distinct()
    .take(5)
    .toMutableList()
}

val result2 = generateSequence { Random.nextInt(1..90) }
  .distinct()
  .take(15)
  .chunked(5) { it.toMutableList() }
  .toMutableList()
```

The first version will create 3 lists with each 5 elements unique within the respective list. The second version will create 3 lists with 15 unique elements in 3 lists at each 5 elements.

Edit: changed both version to return  MutableList<MutableList>.

Comment: In result2 I get List<Int>, but how can i get MutableList<Int>?

Comment: The thing is that I need 15 unique numbers, which I can remove later.

Comment: For a MutableList use _toMutableList()_ instead _toList()_

Comment: "..., which I can remove later" – Remove from what? From 1..90 ? Is the idea to get 6 x 15 numbers = 90 ?

Comment: If I use .toMutableList(), I get  MutableList<List<Int>>, but I need  MutableList<MutableList<Int>>

Comment: I need 15 unique elements over all three lines